# CarrierWave doesn't save file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

Hi I have problem with uploading file via carrierwave, When i am ulpading it with form for nested objects it doesn't work - i have an request, i don't have errors, everything works fine, but it don't save file. I receive i params something like this:

```
[0] {
  "id" => "",
  "name" => "AVATARDALEJNIEDZIALA",
  "surname" => "something",
  "nick" => "123123",
  "image" => "example-midnight-run-artwork.png"
},
```

It create empty files.

/new

```
<%= render 'multi_form'%>
```

/_multi_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag batch_create_employees_path do %>
    <% @employees.each_with_index do |employee, i| %>
    <div class="single-employee-fieldset">
      <div class="row">
          <p class="span12 text-error">
            <%= employee.errors.full_messages.join(', ') %>
          </p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <%= fields_for "employees[]", employee do |employee_form| %>
          <%= employee_form.hidden_field :id %>
          <div class="span3">
            <%= employee_form.text_field :name %>
          </div>
          <div class="span3">
            <%= employee_form.text_field :surname %>
          </div>
          <div class="span3">
            <%= employee_form.text_field :nick %>
          </div>
          <div class="span3">
            <%= employee_form.file_field :image %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  <div class="kontenter"></div>
  <%= submit_tag "Stwórz", :class => 'btn btn-info'%>
<% end %>
```

and it is action in my controller:

```
        attributes = params.permit(employees: [:name, :surname, :nick, :image, :id])[:employees]
    attributes = attributes.select { |attrs| attrs.values.any?(&:present?) }
    @employees = attributes.map do |attrs|
        if attrs[:id].present?
            Employee.find(attrs[:id]).update(attrs)
        else
            p = Employee.create(attrs.merge(active: 1))
        end
    end

    saved, with_errors = @employees.partition { |employee| employee.errors.empty? }

    if with_errors.any?
        render :new
    else
        if attributes.present?
            flash[:success] = "Zostali zapisani #{saved.map {|x| x.name}.join(', ')}"
        end
        redirect_to employees_path
    end
```

Carrierwave works when i am uploading it without nested form, so such as https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

EDIT// add logs

```
Started GET "/employees" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:32 +0200
Processing by EmployeesController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '59dc057f3685ffa672ac20b6c31ebe6145452a06' LIMIT 1
  Employee Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees"
  Rendered employees/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 20ms (Views: 14.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/custom.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/catalogs.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/participants.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/employees.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/clients.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/projects.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/sessions.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/skills.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/users.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/vacations.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/welcome.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/jquery.turbolinks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/raphael.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/catalogs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/morris.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/employees.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/participants.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/projects.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/vacations.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/sessions.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/clients.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/users.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/skills.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/welcome.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 09:29:33 +0200
```

EDIT // add model:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :participants, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :projects, through: :participants
  has_many :vacations
    has_and_belongs_to_many :skills


    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :surname, presence: true

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

 ...
end
```

Comment: Can you add the logs of your console ?

Comment: There appears to be a working example here for you to compare but the guy is complaining about deletes not working.
https://github.com/firedev/cw_nf_rails4

Comment: Can you please post your model here

Comment: I didn't add " multipart: true" in form. Thx for help :)